# Need help with this Geometric sequence problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

First, sorry if Im not using the right syntax, im translating the problem and im not sure if im supposed to say "Sequence" or "series", and also thanks to who ever tries to help.

The sum of a geometric  sequence is 20, and the sum of its squared terms is 205.
find how many terms are in the sequence if the first term is $\frac{1}{2}$.

$a$<sub>1</sub>  + $a$<sub>2</sub>  + $a$<sub>3</sub>  +...+$a$<sub>$n$</sub>  = 20

$a$<sub>1</sub> <sup>2</sup> + $a$<sub>2</sub> <sup>2</sup> + $a$<sub>3</sub> <sup>2</sup> +...+$a$<sub>$n$</sub> <sup>2</sup> = 205

$a$<sub>1</sub> = $\frac{1}{2}$

find $n$.

$20=\frac{a\left(q^n-1\right)}{q-1}$   ==>     $205=\frac{10.25a\left(q^n-1\right)}{q-1}$

$205=\frac{a^2\left(q^{2n}-1\right)}{q^2-1}$ = $\frac{a^2\left(q^n-1\right)\left(q^n+1\right)}{\left(q-1\right)\left(q+1\right)}$

$\frac{10.25a\left(q^n-1\right)}{q-1}$ =$\frac{a^2\left(q^n-1\right)\left(q^n+1\right)}{\left(q-1\right)\left(q+1\right)}$

$10.25a\left(q^n-1\right)\left(q+1\right)$ = $a^2\left(q^n-1\right)\left(q^n+1\right)$

$20.5\left(q+1\right)\space =\space \left(q^n+1\right)$

This is basically where I tell myself i did something wrong.

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series? Note that $a_1^2 + a_2^2 + \cdots + a_n^2$ is a geometric series with ratio $r^2$ if the ratio for the original series is $r$. Apply the formula for each series, giving two equations in the two unknowns $n$ and $r$, and solve.

Comment: There must be a clever trick for the algebra in this one. 
I do know the formulas but fail to get something out of them.

Comment: but how u got  $205=\frac{10.25a\left(q^n-1\right)}{q-1}$??

Comment: @david I just multiplied $20=\frac{a\left(q^n-1\right)}{q-1}$ by 10.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found that $q^n+1=20.5(q+1)$.

But since the sum of the terms is $20$, we have $q^n-1=40(q-1)$.  (In essence you had written down this equation also.)

Subtract, and find  $q$, and then $n$.  The numbers are disappointingly small, $3$ and $4$ respectively.

Comment: We have used the two facts to get $q^n+1=(20.5)(q+1)$. The first fact is still true, so we can use it again. Thus there is nothing logically wrong with the process. And it works! There are other ways to do it that are messier. For example we have from the first that $q^n=40q-39$. Square this to get a formula for $q^{2n}$. Use the second to get another formula for $q^{2n}$. Set the two equal to each other, and solve for $q$.